# Selenium and Chrome error: session not created exception

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I was using selenium with chrome perfectly until chrome updated to version 54.0

After the update, selenium crashes on lunch giving the next traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/user/proyectos_git/venv/backend/venv_backend/venv/management/commands/get_climate_data.py", line 126, in handle
    start_process()
  File "/Users/user/proyectos_git/venv/backend/venv_backend/venv/management/commands/get_climate_data.py", line 105, in start_process
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()  # Initialize webdriver
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 90, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 177, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, capabilities)
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: session not created exception
    from unknown error: bad inspector message: {"method":"Page.loadEventFired","params":{"timestamp":1355138,725669}}
  (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.98)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426935 (820a95b0b81d33e42712f9198c215f703412e1a1),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.1 x86_64)
```

What I've tried:

- Use different chromedriver versions (from 2.16 to 2.25)
- Downgrade the Chrome app (versions 53, 52 and 51)
- Delete my Default folder on the path

  `/Users/user/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/`

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled across this, while searching for an explanation for the fix i found, but it seems to be a locale Problem.
Try prefixing the command with

```
$ LANG=en_US-UTF8 yourcommand
```